# get product in controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_edit observer

Tags: event-observer, magento-1

i'm writing a observer based on this event

`controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_edit`

```
public function currentUser(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
   $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

}
```

But i can't get the product through the event object which is null, how can i get product through this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the product object through this event because this event is just a call when Edit method is called in product controller.

## Controller is called when product is edit.

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action

public function editAction()

{
     Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_edit_action', array('product' =>  $product));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be getting the id of the product which is getting edited with the following code and once you get the id you can load the product

```
public function productEdit($observer){
    $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
}
```

Comment: i already found a answer alternative way of finding product id  as same as your answer, thanks for your reply